# Why does Node.js convert BOM character to 0xFE 0xFF?

Tags: javascript, node.js, character-encoding

I have been working with node's `fs.readFileSync()`, passing `"utf8"` as the encoding to read input. When the file contains a [BOM character](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-byte-order-mark) in UTF8 (0xEF 0xBF 0xBB) it converts it to the byte sequence 0xFE 0xFF instead, which is the Unicode encoding.

Why does it do this? Why not keep the origin sequence for BOMs in UTF8?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The BOM is character U+FEFF. 0xEF 0xBB 0xBF is its UTF-8 representation. But by reading with an encoding of utf8, you're *decoding* UTF-8. At this point it becomes meaningless to talk about a "byte sequence"; you have a string of *characters*, the first of which is U+FEFF.

Comment: So what is the binary value of the BOM character in the string now? Is it 0xFE 0xFF? I'm having trouble understanding the difference between byte sequences and the characters that are basically byte sequences as well i.e. 0xFE 0xFF is a byte sequence...

Comment: @RickEyre As a `String`, it should be a single, 16-bit code point -- U+FEFF or `'\uFEFF'`. And, the difference is that JavaScript `String`s are [based on UTF-16](http://es5.github.io/#x4.3.16). So, to get a `String` from a UTF-8 `Buffer`, it has to be converted to UTF-16.